# When I submit ajax request to the specific URL, it get changed and give 405 (method not allowed)?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, phpunit

This is my ajax call to the URL,

```
update()
    {
       axios.patch("/replies/"+this.attribute.id,
                {
                    body:this.body
                });
    }
```

This the requsted route in web.php

```
Route::patch("/replies/{replies}",[RepliesController::class,"update"])->name("replies.update");
```

It is the error in which it is giving and changing the requested url

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/threads/youtube/6
Request Method: PATCH
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I have written a test, and it passing successfully but when I ajax it, it creating that error

```
    /** @test */
    public function authenticated_user_can_delete_reply()
    {

        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $user = User::factory()->create();
        $this->be($user);
        $reply = Replies::factory()->create(['user_id'=>$user->id]);
        $body = 'My Fucking body.';
        $this->patch("/replies/".$reply->id,["body"=>$body]);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas("replies",[
          "user_id"=>$user->id,
          "body"=>$body
        ]);

    }
```

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. ***[Do some research](https://www.google.com/search?q=patch+405+vue+laravel+route+site:stackoverflow.com)*** , search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)